# How to break word into two parts and put them under each other

Tags: html, css

I want to make a menubar that looks like this: 
[image]

So the words should be cut in the middle and placed under each other like this:

epi-
 sodes

```css
 ul{
list-style-type: none;
font-size: 20pt;
}


li{
display: inline;
padding: 0px 30px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu"> 
  <div id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
  <div id="panel">  
  <ul>
      <li> EPIS- ODER </li>
      <li> KARAK- TERER </li>
      <li> OM- OSS </li>
      <li> PRODU- KSJON </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

All help is appreciated!:)

Comment: What about the <br> tag? It should work to break any line.

Comment: yeah sure, but isn't that "bad" coding? wondered if there was a more elegant way:p

Comment: Depends if different resolutions or other CSS would ruin the style. If nothing really ruins it and it looks fine, then by all means the simplest solution is the best one (nothing ugly about simple things, after all).

Comment: Not really a duplicate...

Comment: @ovokuro how is it not - OP wants to break the word and add hyphens

Comment: I don't even know how to use hyphens though...

Comment: @In6ify have a look at the answers, there's some good options - either using css or using &shy; (soft hypen)